# Is there any way to get system idle time on all platforms

Tags: node.js, electron

I am making an electron app to check system idle time. I want to use a common module to get idle time on winodws, mac and linux.

I am using this command to get idle time on mac but it is not working in linux.
i also tried different npm plugins to get idle time but none of them is working as expected

```
function idleTime(callback) {
  var command = `ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print $NF/1000000000; exit}'`;
  child_process.exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    return err ? callback(err) : callback(null, stdout.trim());
  });
```

my expected result is to check if the user is using system or not. i wanted to calculate idle time of sysem on all platforms (mac,linux,windows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect desktop idle time from an Electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398499/how-to-detect-desktop-idle-time-from-an-electron-app)

Comment: This question has been already answered in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398499/how-to-detect-desktop-idle-time-from-an-electron-app).

Answer (score 0):

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor#powermonitorquerysystemidlestateidlethreshold-callback

```
powerMonitor.querySystemIdleTime(callback)
callback Function

idleTime Integer - Idle time in seconds
Calculate system idle time in seconds.
```

Electron have built-in support for checking idle time (and state).

Comment: I am trying this but it gives " Cannot read property 'querySystemIdleTime' of undefined" this error. can you explain a bit more I am new to electron

Comment: You may have a look at the code example at the beginning of the provided [link](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor#powermonitorquerysystemidlestateidlethreshold-callback) to know how to obtain the `powerMonitor` variable, and comply with the fact that the call must be performed from the main process, after the `ready` event of the `app` module is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but for newcomers look at [Electron Power monitor API's](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor)

```
const {powerMonitor} = require('electron'); 
const idle = powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime() // it returns in seconds when I am writing this
console.log('Current System Idle Time - ', idle);
```